# Is it possible to conditionally format a WPF datagrid row based on an aggregate?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I load a datagrid from SQL then bind it with

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
```

dt being my datatable. I know how to highlight a row based on an explicit value in one of the columns:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding someNumberA}" Value="1">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

But say I have two columns someNumberA and someNumberB and want to highlight the row based on a boolean aggregate, like if sNA-sNB > 5 then red. Is this possible in XAML, if not, then how else can I do it, since I never explicitly created the class with methods, just loaded straight from the datatable? Right now I do have a way of making it work through creating a boolean column in SQL so I have the explicit T/F value then highlighting off of that and hiding the column. Thanks for any input.

After the suggestion I use a converter, I came up with a very good working solution.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="False">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CheckGreaseTolerance}">
                            <Binding Path = "GREASE_UPPER"/>
                            <Binding Path ="GREASE_LOWER"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

And the class that it calls:

```
Public Class CheckGreaseTolerance
    Implements IMultiValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(values() As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IMultiValueConverter.Convert
        Dim GU As Decimal = CDec(values(0))
        Dim GL As Decimal = CDec(values(1))
        If GU - GL > 2 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have modifiable view models for your data items, you would add a boolean property that exposes the aggregate result, just like your alternative approach with a separate column in SQL.

In XAML you *could* use [value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data) for different types of aggregate functions and use them in a data trigger. You can either create an [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netcore-3.1) and bind your data row or a [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=netcore-3.1) to pass specific properties of your data row directly or even bind other properties e.g. from the parent data context.

A value converter for your example of *someNumberA - someNumberB > 5* could look like this, taking in a `DataGridRow` as value and a `double` parameter for comparison.

```
public class SampleAggregateConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      var dataRowView = (DataRowView)value;
      return (double)dataRowView["someNumberA"] - (double)dataRowView["someNumberB"] > (double)parameter;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("This conversion is one-way only.");
   }
}
```

Then in your row style you can apply the data trigger by binding the row and using the converter.

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
   <DataTrigger.Binding>
      <Binding Converter="{StaticResource SampleAggregateConverter}">
         <Binding.ConverterParameter>
            <system:Double>5.0</system:Double>
         </Binding.ConverterParameter>
      </Binding>
   </DataTrigger.Binding>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The binding is a bit verbose, because assigning the `ConverterParameter` directly would result in it being passed as `string` to the converter. A multi-value converter could be useful to allow you to bind the parameter value.

Comment: Really appreciate the response, I hadn't thought of using a converter (well I've never used one before so that may be the reason. I used your idea and tweaked it a bit to get to work for me. I'm going to update my code with my solution in case anyone happens to see this and need it.